# SQL sum with group by

Tags: sql, group-by

Below is the list entry:

```
GROUPNUMBER|COUNTRY|COUNT|AMOUNT
BD2        |US     |4    |2.00
BD2        |US     |10   |8.00
BD2        |CANADA |12   |10.00
BD5        |UK     |2    |1.00
BD5        |US     |6    |4.00
BD5        |UK     |8    |6.00
```

Result output needed:

```
GROUPNUMBER|US_COUNT|US_AMOUNT|NON_US_COUNT|NON_US_AMOUNT
BD2        |14      |10.00    |12          |10.00
BD5        |6       |4.00     |10          |7.00
```

Need to separate the count and amount with US and NON_US and group by GroupNumber  field.
is this possible in MS SQL?

Thanks,
Subs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be doable with a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT
    GROUPNUMBER,
    SUM(CASE WHEN COUNTRY = 'US' THEN [COUNT] ELSE 0 END) AS US_COUNT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN COUNTRY = 'US' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS US_AMOUNT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN COUNTRY != 'US' THEN [COUNT] ELSE 0 END) AS NON_US_COUNT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN COUNTRY != 'US' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS NON_US_AMOUNT
FROM theTable
GROUP BY GROUPNUMBER
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a561c/1)

Comment: follow-up question need also a SQL if the value of Country is lower case "us".

Comment: MS SQL Server is case insensitive by default, I believe, so it should work regardless.  If the case does matter, you can use the UPPER() function to force the casing